# Need some help on crontab

Tags: curl, cron

Per the guideline from a post, I have set my cron job like this.

```
0 6 * * * curl [https://]mysite.com/index.php/abc/corn_job > /tmp/croncheck2 2>&1
```

and I saw on log that it's executing correctly, on time.

Unfortunately, it's not executing the task that my developer set to process on that file.

Let me explain a bit in details.

I have a PHP application installed on my subdomain and that file (corn_job) is used for deduct credits of my clients account on appropriate time.

I spoke with my developer, and he says if he sets up a cron job on his hosting, credits are deducted without any problem, but that's on his shared hosting with cPanel, and setting a cron job is really easy there.

The first thing that I suspect is the execute command "curl". Should it be curl in my case or something else?

Comment: Figure out if `curl` is installed. Else `wget`. Or run it per `php` interpreter directly, if accessible on the filesystem. And check the dumped `2>&1` error log, really.

Comment: hi @mario, thanks for your response. i have changed the command to wget and now im getting a new massage. --2015-08-17 03:00:01--  mysite.com/index.php/super/corn_job
Resolving mysite.com (mysite.com)... *****d0::d:4001, 128.199*****
Connecting to mysite.com (mysite.com)|****:0:d0::d:4001|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2015-08-17 03:00:01 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.

Comment: one thing i dont understand, why it says HTTP request sent, awaiting response when my original link is https